# Fetching right score (php)

Tags: php, sql

I'm new to PHP, and I need some help. I can't seem to get the right score for a student.

The scenario:

- Input answers (answer key) for an exam with corresponding points
- Input student-answer for that exam
- Get total score of the student.

My PHP code:

```
for ($count = 1; $count <= $num_ans; $count++)
{
    $answer = $_POST['answer'][($count + 1) - 1];
    $sqlB = "SELECT * FROM paper WHERE id=$count and test_name = '$test_name' and subject='$subject'";
    $qryB = mysql_query($sqlB);
    $rowB = mysql_fetch_array($qryB);
    $anskey = $rowB['answer'];
}
if ($answer = $anskey)
{
    $sqlA = "SELECT points FROM paper WHERE test_name = '$test_name' and subject='$subject' and answer='$answer'";
    $qryA = mysql_query($sqlA);
    while ($rowA = mysql_fetch_array($qryA))
    {
        $correctAns += $rowA['points'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @GrazielleLeotero, if you need a simple PDO example you can use [my class](https://github.com/Xeoncross/DByte).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 for ($count=1; $count<=$num_ans; $count++) {            
        $answer = $_POST['answer'][$count]; 
        $sqlB = "SELECT answer FROM paper WHERE id=$count and test_name = '$test_name' and    subject='$subject'";
        $qryB = mysql_query($sqlB);
        $rowB = mysql_fetch_array($qryB);
        $anskey = $rowB['answer'];

        if ($answer == $anskey) { 
        $sqlA = "SELECT points FROM paper WHERE test_name = '$test_name' and subject='$subject' and answer='$answer'";
        $qryA = mysql_query($sqlA);
         //considering each unique answer would have specific points, while-loop is not required
        //while($rowA = mysql_fetch_array($qryA)) {
        $correctAns += $rowA['points'];
       // }
        }  
} //end of for-loop
```

Comment: the answer still 0. it won't add up.

Comment: still same result. it won't add up. the score i got is still 0.

Comment: whats the value for `$rowA['points']`? are you getting any errors?

Comment: the value is 0. no error messages but instead if I set the total score as 8 with 4 items (2pts/item), lets say 'student' got 2 correct answers, instead of 4 I get 0 out of 8.

Comment: try debugging line-by-line, checking values for `$answer`, `$anskey`...and see if you're getting the expected values.

Comment: are u sure to remove the while loop? what would happen to $rowA?

Answer (score 0):

i think some thing is missing in your database query.

```
$query = "SELECT points FROM paper WHERE test_name = '$test_name' and subject='$subject' and answer='$answer'";
$qryA = mysql_query($query);
while($rowA = mysql_fetch_array($qryA)) {
   $correctAns += $rowA['points'];
}
```

please check :

```
  $rowA['points'] = ??// if any value return from db or not.
```

because SQL Query, please pass question id/(something unique in row) answer = '$answer' may be duplicate so it's can't back actual value.

Hope you understand.

Comment: $rowA['points'] corresponds to the column of points given per item in the database table 'paper'.